# Put an application into a stored procedure?

Tags: jquery, node.js, oracle, stored-procedures, oracle-apex

How do you put an application (like from APEX, Node, or jQuery Mobile) into a Oracle 11g stored procedure?

I can get a stored procedure to print out text, but it seems more complex to get an actual application to output...

Comment: I think maybe you're  confused about what an Oracle stored procedure is best used for.  You wouldn't be expecting to put your entire application into stored procedures.  You'd be expecting to put functions that manage data in the database into stored procedures and then your application (which is outside of stored procedures) can call those stored procedures to carry out various database operations.

Comment: So for example, if you are creating an App in APEX, you would create a stored procedure in Oracle (using Toad for example), then go back to the APEX App and call the procedure?

Comment: That is the general idea.

Comment: If this is a non-trivial application I recommend you use packages to encapsulate the stored procedures and functions.  It's a little extra work but that extra layer of organization can be a real life saver as the application grows.

Comment: Read this to learn a little more about when to use stored procedures: https://www.quora.com/When-would-you-write-database-stored-procedure-instead-of-calling-SQL-from-a-high-level-language